# Build errors AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

When I build my ASP.NET MVC application (VS2013, .net 4.5.1), I am getting these errors.

I have re factored "login.cshtml" by removing complete mark up and did it again. Now I am getting following build errors (red errors). But the build status is "Build Succeed" and application works fine.

So this is specific to my local machine.

```
Error   21  The name 'RenderBody' does not exist in the current context c:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp\vctmp6480_135776.cshtml    61  34  Miscellaneous Files

Error   20  The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context    c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp\vctmp6480_135776.cshtml 34  6   Miscellaneous Files

Error   17  The name 'Styles' does not exist in the current context c:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp\vctmp6480_135776.cshtml    20  6   Miscellaneous Files
```

I have cleaned up the `c:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp` folder. I still get the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. 'Clean' solution
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Delete the entire `.../TFSTemp` folder
4. Get latest sources recursive
5. Reopen solution and rebuild all.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "get the latest sources recursive?"

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was a UI option in the source controls options of Visual Studio, back in 2014